# troubles querying information schema

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

> postgresql server 8.4

With a user with attribute "super user", I can perform this query :

```
SELECT
        ccu.table_name AS master_table, ccu.column_name AS master_column,
        tc.table_name AS child_table, kcu.column_name AS child_column
FROM 
        information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
          ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
        JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
          ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
ORDER BY master_table, master_column
```

With a normal user, I have no errors but also no results.
Which are the minimal permissions ... grants ... to allow a normal user to query the information schema ?

I tried unsuccesfully

> GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA information_schema to user

and also

> grant select on information_schema.constraint_column_usage to user
>
> (and the other two used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only see objects on which you have some permissions:

- You cannot see other users' temporary objects.
- You can see objects whose owner is a role you belong to.
- You can see objects if you have any privileges on the table or its columns.

To bypass these restrictions, you could create a function with `SECURITY DEFINER` that belongs to a superuser and runs the query for you.

Then revoke `EXECUTE` on that function from `PUBLIC` and grant it to the user who needs it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION info_schema_query()
   RETURNS TABLE (
      master_table  information_schema.sql_identifier,
      master_column information_schema.sql_identifier,
      child_table   information_schema.sql_identifier,
      child_column  information_schema.sql_identifier
   )
   LANGUAGE sql STABLE SECURITY DEFINER
   SET search_path = information_schema
AS $$SELECT ...$$;

REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION info_schema_query() FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT  EXECUTE ON FUNCTION info_schema_query() TO j_random_user;
```

Comment: I know ... but I see no solution.

Comment: I have extended the answer - perhaps that's a solution for you.

Comment: Laurenz, thank your for the efforts. I don't understand : is this a permanent solution to give to normal users only the read permissions for that informations ? What is this "function with SECURITY DEFINER" I have to create ?

Comment: I have added an example so that you don't have to look into the documentation (although you still should do that).